# Validate if age is over 18 years old

Tags: php

Just wondering, can I do this to validate that a user has entered a date over 18?

```
//Validate for users over 18 only
function time($then, $min)
{
    $then = strtotime('March 23, 1988');
    //The age to be over, over +18
    $min = strtotime('+18 years', $then);
    echo $min;
    if (time() < $min) {
        die('Not 18');
    }
}
```

Just stumbled across this function date_diff:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php
Looks, even more promising.

Comment: I hope this isn't for something of top security! ;-) I'm sure that all kids trying to access Adult content will enter their correct age.

Comment: No, I am just learning about php, it's probably more like no security at all.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Why not? The only problem to me, is the User Interface - how you send out the error message elegantly to the user.

On another note, your function might not work properly as you did not intake a proper birthday (you are using a fixed birthday). You should change 'March 23, 1988' to $then

```
//Validate for users over 18 only
function validateAge($then, $min)
{
    // $then will first be a string-date
    $then = strtotime($then);
    //The age to be over, over +18
    $min = strtotime('+18 years', $then);
    echo $min;
    if(time() < $min)  {
        die('Not 18'); 
    }
}
```

Or you can:

```
// validate birthday
function validateAge($birthday, $age = 18)
{
    // $birthday can be UNIX_TIMESTAMP or just a string-date.
    if(is_string($birthday)) {
        $birthday = strtotime($birthday);
    }

    // check
    // 31536000 is the number of seconds in a 365 days year.
    if(time() - $birthday < $age * 31536000)  {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Also, remember that a year is technically 365.242199 days in a year. So you should be multiplying by 31556926 instead of 31536000. Also, Google is really nice about these kinds of calculations, just ask Google "1 years in seconds" :)

Comment: The above comment is talking about with leap year added on obviously. Maybe make a boolean option in your method to enable / disable that option?

Comment: That's really neat, I was just going to spend a couple of hours wading through like a million different ways to validate an age
from here: http://www.php.net, thank you. The comments are superb, again thank you.

Comment: Just realized you can rank comments, leet.

Comment: Keep in mind that age should be calculated using string comparissons and not using math, however you can get pretty close using math.

Comment: Prefer the first function seems more safe with irregular years and real amount of seconds in a year

Comment: In 18 years, there are 4 or 5 possible leap years. So multiplying 365 days with 18 will always be 4 or 5 days short of 18 years. This is not a good idea for a mission critical system. A reliable and simple approach would be to use strtotime('+18 years', strtotime($date_of_birth)) for accuracy. I used it for a banking system with thousands of clients, so I know from experience it is accurate.

Answer (score 20):

Here is a simplified extract from what I used for a banking system in Toronto, and this always worked perfectly, taking account of leap years of 366 days.

```
/* $dob is date of birth in format 1980-02-21 or 21 Feb 1980
 * time() is current server unixtime
 * We convert $dob into unixtime, add 18 years, and check it against server's
 * current time to validate age of under 18
 */

if (time() < strtotime('+18 years', strtotime($dob))) {
   echo 'Client is under 18 years of age.';
   exit;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I think it is best using the DateTime class for this.

```
$bday = new DateTime("22-10-1993");  
$bday->add(new DateInterval("P18Y")); //adds time interval of 18 years to bday  
//compare the added years to the current date  
if($bday < new DateTime()){   
    echo "over 18";  
}else{  
    echo "below 18";
}
```

DateTime::diff can also be used to compare the date with the current date.

```
$today = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d"));
$bday = new DateTime("22-10-1993");
$interval = $today->diff($bday);
if(intval($interval->y) > 18){
    echo "older than 18";
}else{
    echo "younger than 18";
}
```

N/B: 1) for the second method , if $bday is greater than $today by 18 years or more, it will return older , so make sure date entered is less than $today
. 2) DateTime works on php 5.2.0 and above

Comment: It is not a good experience. Probably you will save this data to database after validation. If you print ```$bday``` you will se its changed. You should create new DateTime object like ```$bdayPlus18y = new \DateTime($bday->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));``` then if...

Answer (score 2):

```
if( strtotime("1988/03/23") < (time() - (18 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365))) {
  print "yes";
} else {
  print "no";
}
```

...not accounting for leaps years however

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
 $dob = $_POST['dob'] ?? ''; 
 $message = '';

 # Validate Date of Birth
 if (empty($dob)){
  # the user's date of birth cannot be a null string
  $message = 'Please submit your date of birth.';
 }
 elseif (!preg_match('~^([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4})$~', $dob, $parts)){
  # Check the format
  $message = 'The date of birth is not a valid date in the format MM/DD/YYYY';
 }
 elseif (!checkdate($parts[1],$parts[2],$parts[3])){
  $message = 'The date of birth is invalid. Please check that the month is between 1 and 12, and the day is valid for that month.';
 }
 
 if ($message == '') {
  # Convert date of birth to DateTime object
  $dob =  new DateTime($dob);

  $minInterval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('18 years');
  $maxInterval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('120 years');
 
  $minDobLimit = ( new DateTime() )->sub($minInterval);
  $maxDobLimit = ( new DateTime() )->sub($maxInterval);
 
  if ($dob <= $maxDobLimit)
   # Make sure that the user has a reasonable birth year
   $message = 'You must be alive to use this service.';
   # Check whether the user is 18 years old.
  elseif ($dob >= $minDobLimit) {
   $message = 'You must be 18 years of age to use this service.';
  }
 
  if ($message == '') {
   $today = new DateTime();
   $diff = $today->diff($dob);
   $message = $diff->format('You are %Y years, %m months and %d days old.');
  }
 }
?>
----------------------------------
<p><b><?=$message?></b></p>
<form method="post" action="">
Your date of birth: <br>
<input type="text" name="dob" id="dob" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY"><br>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML Input:

```
 <input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="Data of Birth" name="dateOfBirth">
```

PHP code:

```
function validateDateOfBirth($birthDay)
    {
// convert user input date to string and +18 years;
// compare user input date with current date;

        if (time() < strtotime('+18 years', strtotime($birthDay))) {
            return 'Not 18';
        }
        return "user is older than 18 years old";
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Php file

```
if (isset($_POST['bdate'])){
    $bdate = $_POST['bdate'];
    $age = (date("Y-m-d") - $bdate);



}  //if age if 17 or younger error msg
if ($age < 17) {
    echo "Must 18 or older.";
}
else{ //if age is 120 or greather error msg
    if ($age > 120) {
        echo "Real age please.";
    }
    else{
        echo "$age";
    }
}
```

HTML code:

```
<form action="" method="POST"> 

    <p><label>Birth Date &nbsp;&nbsp;: </label>
    <input id="bdate" type="date" name="bdate" required placeholder="" /></p>
    <input class="btn register" type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" />
</form>
```