# PHP determine age of customer

Tags: php

Im trying to make sure that my customrs are over  the age of 18. So far i have done this by taking the date of birth and the current data and finding the difference between the two.

```
$diff=date_diff(date_create($DOB),date_create(date("Y-m-d")));
echo $diff->format("%R%a days");
if ($diff<6574){
    $D_error="You must be ages 18+ to make a booking";
}
```

The difference found is correct ( the correct value is shown) but an error occurs when it tries to see if $diff<6574.
The error is : Notice: Object of class DateInterval could not be converted to int
I assume this has something to so with the fact that $diff is a time interval and therefore cannot be compared to an integer.
 How would i get past this problem?
And is the whole thing:

```
if (empty($_POST["DOB"])){
    $D_error="DOB is required";
}elseif (!preg_match("/^[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$/",$DOB)){
    $D_error="DOB must be given in the form yyyy-mm-dd";
}else{
$diff=date_diff(date_create($DOB),date_create(date("Y-m-d")));
echo $diff->format("%R%a days");
if ($diff->days < 6574){{
    $D_error="You must be ages 18+ to make a booking";
}

}
```

But with this i get an unexpected end to file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812589/validate-if-age-is-over-18-years-old

Comment: You should use `if ($diff->format("%R%a") < 6574){`.

Comment: i tried that but i just get an unexpected end to file

Answer (score 1):

`$diff` is an object, and you can't compare an object to an integer.
What you are looking for is the `days` property of the object.

Your comparison should look like this:

```
if($diff->days < 6574)
    //...
```

As a sidenote, the object also has other interesting properties, for example `y`, which is the number of years. So you could also simply use the following comparison:

```
if($diff->y < 18)
    //...
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in your if statement. Date_diff function returns instance of DateInterval object (http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php), so you can't compare it to the integer. Use any property of DateInterval object, such as $days, or even $y (years), so something like:

```
if ($diff->y < 18)
```

Answer (score 0):

date_diff returns DateInterval which has a public property days. So try this

```
if ($diff->days < 6574){
    $D_error="You must be ages 18+ to make a booking";
}
```